# An invertible sheaf is algebraic equivalent to 0 iff its degree is 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be a field, $X$ a smooth geometrically connected projective curve over $k$, and $\mathscr{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $X$.
Then I think that $\mathscr{L}$ is algebraic equivalent to $\mathscr{O}_X$ if and only if $\deg \mathscr{L}= 0$.
But I can't find references.

(two invertible sheaves $\mathscr{L}, \mathscr{N}$ are algebraic equivalent if for some $n \ge 1$ and for all $1 \le i \le n$, there exists a connected $k$-scheme of finite type $T_i$ and geometric points $t_i, s_i$ in $T_i$ with the same field, and an invertible sheaf $\mathscr{M}_i$ on $X_{T_i}$ such that $\mathscr{L}_{s_1} \cong \mathscr{M}_{1, s_1}, \mathscr{M}_{1, t_1} \cong \mathscr{M}_{2, s_2}, \dots , \mathscr{M}_{n, t_n} \cong \mathscr{N}_{t_n}$.)

The "only if" part is clear, since the degree is invariant under base changes.
How can I show the "if" part?
Or are there some references?

Using fppf descent, we may assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.
And using Weil divisors, we may assume that $\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{O}_X(P - Q)$ for closed points $P, Q \in X$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What definition of algebraic equivalence are you using?

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for your comment. I edited it.

Comment: There is a map $X \rightarrow Pic^0(X)$, given by $Q \mapsto \mathcal{O}_X(P-Q)$. Thus by the universal property of Pic^0, we get a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $X \times X$, such that $\mathcal{L}|_{X \times Q} \cong \mathcal{O}_X(P-Q)$ and $\mathcal{L}|_{X \times P} \cong \mathcal{O}_X$. I suppose that the existence of such a map to jacobian might be seen first in the analytic sense and then perhaps use GAGA to get an algebraic map.

Comment: @random123 Thank you very much!